# How to set the spaces in a string format in Python 3

Tags: python, variables, string-formatting, python-3.5

How can I set up the string format so that I could use a variable to ensure the length can change as needed? For example, lets say the length was 10 at first, then the input changes then length becomes 15. How would I get the format string to update?

```
    length =  0
    for i in self.rows:
        for j in i:
            if len(j) > length:
                length  = len(j)
    print('% length s')
```

Obviously the syntax above is wrong but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? Are you trying to print within the for loop?

Comment: please show example input and expected output.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `print(s)`? It will print whatever `s` is.

Comment: BTW, you can replace that nested loop with `max(map(len, (j for i in rows for j in i)))`

Comment: @tobias_k shorter and more readable way: `max(len(j) for i in rows for j in i)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `str.format`

```
>>> length = 20
>>> string = "some string"
>>> print('{1:>{0}}'.format(length, string))
         some string
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `%*s` and pass in `length` as another parameter:

```
>>> length = 20
>>> string = "some string"
>>> print("%*s" % (length, string))
         some string
```

Or use a format string to create the format string:

```
>>> print(("%%%ds" % length) % string)
         some string
```

Answer (score 1):

The `format` method allows nice keyword arguments combined with positional arguments:

```
>>> s = 'my string'
>>> length = 20
>>> '{:>{length}s}'.format(s, length=length)
'           my string'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare like this:

```
 print('%20s'%'stuff')
```

20 would be the number of characters in the print string. The excess in whitespace.

Comment: length changes the amount of white space, it isnt what gets printed

Comment: I just printed it. I'm pretty sure I'm seeing white space.

Comment: The OP is trying to get a format string that does not depend on knowing the length ahead of time.  He wants to be able to change the length, but use the same format string.  tobias_k's answer should give you the idea.

Comment: tobias_k answer is indeed a more complete example (although the solution is the same,... I think). Should I delete my post?