# How to write to the file with a variable .format?

Tags: python, file, python-2.x

I want to write two strings into a file with variable white-spaces between. Here's the code I wrote:

```
width = 6
with open(out_file, 'a') as file:
    file.write("{:width}{:width}\n".format('a', 'b'))
```

But I get `ValueError: Invalid conversion specification` from it. I expected it to write characters *a* and *b* with 6 spaces between in one line into the file.

I am using python 2.

Comment: Please provide more information. What are you expecting to be done? What is your goal when writing this code?

Comment: I am trying to printout certain format to the file example, "a          b        " , the empty space between word is something i want to control in this case.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the details to it, so everyone can see it when they are trying to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the format string a little and pass `width` as a keyword argument to the `format()` method:

```
width = 6
with open(out_file, 'a') as file:
    file.write("{:{width}}{:{width}}\n".format('a', 'b', width=width))
```

Contents of file afterwards:

```
a     b
```

Comment: This one goes well, thanks, i think it fits perfectly for what i looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly but you can do this. Using `{{}}` you can type a literal curly brace, and by that, you can format your format string with a variable width.

```
width = 6

format_str = "{{:{}}}{{:{}}}\n".format(width, width) #This makes the string "{:width}{:width}" with a variable width.


with open(out_file, a) as file:
    file.write(format_str.format('a','b'))
```

EDIT: If you want to apply this type of variable width pattern to any of your patterns used in a code, you could use this function:

```
import re
def variable_width_pattern(source_pattern, width):
    regex = r"\{(.*?)\}"
    matches = re.findall(regex, source_pattern)
    args = ["{{:{}}}".format(width) for x in range(len(matches))]
    return source_pattern.format(*args)
```

Comment: This is a bit difficult because i actually have tons of line that required different variable for the space format, and by doing this it required double of the lines to accomplish the work.

Comment: @user1550596 Well this is the solution. You could define a function which takes a `width` and the source pattern, and then produces the `format_str` by putting the formatted curly braces inside your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I googled a little and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138895/how-to-set-the-spaces-in-a-string-format-in-python-3?answertab=active#tab-top). With some changes, I wrote this code which I tried and got your desired output:

```
width = 6
with open(out_file, 'a') as file:
    f.write("{1:<{0}}{2}\n".format(width, 'a', 'b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple multiplication will work here
(multiplication operator is overloaded here)

```
width = 6
charector = ' '
with open(out_file, 'a') as file:
    file.write('a' + charector * width + 'b')
```